# Does updating to Android 11 require an app to show another location permission dialog if location is used in the background?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

As some of you may know, google made a lot of changes to background location permission and permissions in general in Android 11. Their docs explain it very thoroughly but the question in the topic remains a mystery.

Does updating a device to Android 11 require an app that already had the user permission to "always" fetch for location to show the location permission dialog again?

Comment: 1- first need to have some of these permissions: ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ou ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. 

2- Now, you must ask for the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission. This one only can be set in the device setting's screen. So first you must explain what the user needs to do on that system screen because it's up to them to choose the right options.

3- as the user can choose to allow one time while using the app or ask for permission every time, the permissions verification must be constantly checked in your code to prevent access denial exceptions.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. The user already gave "always-on" permission to the app while on Android 10. Does that mean that on Android 11 the same app will have 'ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION' permission or the permission dialog needs to be presented again on order to gain that permission?

Answer (score 0):

No. If an app already has background location permission, then an update of OS to 11 won't affect anything. The app will continue to have "Allow all the time" if it already has it.

Also, if an app is not targeted for Android SDK 29 or 30 then the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION is not needed. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION itself will ask for "Allow all the time" option as well on Android 11.

For more details, visit this - https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions